# how to compute conditional expectation in markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

how would the processes of computing a conditional expectation on a discrete time markov chain normally go about?
Given a markov chain with states $\{1,2,\dots, N\}$ with given transition probabilities. How should I handle computing $\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|X_{n}=i) $?

Is it true that 
$$\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|X_{n}=i)=\sum_k^N kP(X_{n+1}|X_{n}=i) =\sum_k^N kp_{ij}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single "conditional expectation". The expected value always depends on *what* you're trying to calculate.

For example, let's say we have a discrete Markov chain with state-space $\left\{0, 1, ..., N\right\}$ where each state $i$ represents gaining $i$ golden coins. Let's say that we are looking for the expected value of golden coins we'll gain tomorrow given that today we found $k$ coins:

$$ E(X_1|X_0 = k)=\sum_{i=0}^N iP(X_1=i|X_0=k) = \sum_{i=0}^N ip_{ki} $$

If we are looking for the expected coins we'll gain in **two days**, the above won't generally work and you'll need to take the square of the transition matrix and calculate the respective probability.

Comment: I have so much to learn. Thank you for taking the time to answer, I think I'll spend some time reading up instead of asking. Answer accepted.